# Career advice for a Physics PhD Student?

Tags: phd, career-path, job-search, industry, physics

I am currently in the first year of my physics Ph.D. program focused on condensed matter physics. While in undergrad, I specialized in optics which I also enjoyed. I just joined a research group focused on small angle neutron scatteringrg.

I want to transition into the industry sector after graduating and know I want to apply my condensed matter physics knowledge even if it isn't directly related to my group's research emphasis. However, I am not opposed to using the math, physics, and experimental research skills I have been developing in a less directly related career path. I was wondering if anyone had suggestions for potential career paths, career path resources, or just any general advice on future careers?

Comment: Don’t forget the various national labs...

Comment: This would be a great question for your supervisor.

Answer (score 4):

Internships. An internship or two will give you a taste of what a nonacademic career might entail and give your employers insight into you as a potential candidate. It's not uncommon for employers to view internships as a sort of extended interview. I have no doubt you'll learn things and see things you hadn't anticipated, perhaps interesting paths to follow. Best of luck!